# Do not show inserted HTML in DIV as tags; rather show it as normal display of tags

Tags: asp.net, html, tinymce

I am using TinyMce to compose emails then I am saving emails in database. There need to open email in read only mode as well. Top show mail just in readonly mode I inserted email tags in a `div` but in display inserted text was not begin shown as a display of HTML tags, rather tags where there in `div`. I am using `div.InnerHtml` to add email HTML but `div` is showing tags like:

```
<p>
 <strong>hi,</strong>
</p>
<div>
 <span style="color: #800000;">
  Since the application that he demands require information gathering,
  screen designing and development, I have forwarded the project to the team
  I am working with.
 </span>
</div>
<div><br /></div>
<div>
 <span style="color: #ff6600;">
  <strong>
   <span style="font-size: medium;">Thanks,</span>
  </strong>
 </span>
</div>
<div>
 <strong>
  <span style="font-size: medium;"><br /> </span>
 </strong>
</div>
<div style="text-align: right;">
 <span style="font-size: medium;">
  <em>
   <span style="text-decoration: underline;">
    <span style="color: #339966;">Mr. Bota</span>
   </span>
  </em>
 </span>
 <br />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you saying you want to show the _rendered_ html?

Comment: I dont want to show it as tags. I want to display these tags.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla, I dont want to display it as tags. Rather I want to dispaly result of these tags, as they appear normally in html pages.

Comment: You need to provide a bit more context. Where is this HTML coming from? Are you building it in the code-behind, is it coming from the database?

Comment: I gotcha, that's typically referred to as the `rendered` html.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an asp.net `Literal` control, and set the `LiteralMode` to `PassThrough'.  You can read a bit more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literalmode.aspx.

This should allow the HTML you emit to actually be rendered, instead of seeing the tags.

Comment: but why they are not beign displayed in div ? I was expecting div will display it as rendered html. any way I can use div ?

Comment: Because normally, for security reasons, when you write something to a page it's encoded, this prevents at lot of different possible attacks.  Even after accepting the input from TinyMce, you should really do some sanitation before writing out the results, specifically looking for and removing `<script>` tags.

Comment: @Coading Gorilla, same results. It looks like issue is not this.

Comment: Can you update your question and show some code and/or markup so we can see what you're doing?

Answer (score 1):

Use a literal control for this:

```
<asp:Literal ID="litEmailBody" runat="server" />
```

And in the code behind:

```
litEmailBody.Text = htmlContent; //your HTML markup
```

Comment: Are you HTML encoding the markup? Make sure to decode the markup before assigning it to the Literal.